# OpenCV: cvThreshold is crashing with certain images sizes

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to filter out noise from an image. The size of the image changes from time to time. It seems that cvThreshold can only handle images with certain sizes. This code is working (although it does nothing):

```
IplImage* iplTresh = cvCreateImage(cvSize(65, 49), 8, 1);
cvThreshold(iplTresh, iplTresh, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cvReleaseImage(&iplTresh);
```

This code is crashing (width changed from 65 to 89):

```
IplImage* iplTresh = cvCreateImage(cvSize(89, 49), 8, 1);
cvThreshold(iplTresh, iplTresh, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cvReleaseImage(&iplTresh);
```

error message:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007ffff1529da7 in cv::threshold(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int) ()
from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance,
cheers

Comment: I ran your code (with OpenCV 2.3.1) and I'm not seeing any crashes. What other code to you have executing near this? What version of OpenCV are you using?